# What are license terms for Biztalk Server 2009 Developer Edition?

Tags: licensing, biztalk, eula

Where can I find the license terms for Microsoft Biztalk Server? (especially the Developer license).

I've found the [pricing and licensing page](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/pricing-licensing.aspx), which links to a FAQ - but I can't find the actual legal document anywhere (i.e. the actual license terms).
The closest is a 100+ page document of "user rights" - but it is only the changes from previous licenses (and it covers *all* their products).

Comment: They're doing you a favour; making it so hard to find out that you won't use it :)

Comment: This question is off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[About Licensing/Product Licensing](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/product-licensing.aspx#tab=1)
and [BizTalk Server 2009 Developer Edition](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/userights/ProductPage.aspx?pid=282).

It's organized as diffs from more general documents.